# Alternative to Call Log or SMS permissions banned

Tags: logging, permissions, sms, call

Android Mobile App removed from Google Playstore because of Call Log or SMS permissions

I have tried to remove the permission from Manifest but its break the app as the app requires these permission.

What should I do to make sure my application still able to run. Alternative to the Call Log or SMS permissions on Android studio

Answer (score 1):

The permission restrictions were added for added privacy security to the user.

[find a quick read on the affected permissions here](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)

However, there are alternative implementations available for the use cases which needs these dangerous permissions.

1. [SMS OTP & account verification](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)
2. [Initiate a text message](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#SendMessage)
3. [Share Content](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/)
4. [Initiate a phone call](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_DIAL)

Find the use case in your project where these permissions are needed and replace with the alternative implementations.